# HTML Agility Pack <pre> tag

Tags: c#, tags, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape website that has a "pre" tag using the HTML Agility Pack in C#.  I can find plenty of "table tr td" examples but cannot find any "pre"examples. Here is my code with the formatted text "pre"  inline.

```
private void PreformattedTextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var url = @"http://www.thepredictiontracker.com/basepred.php";
        var data = new MyWebClient().DownloadString(url);
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(data);

        //            m _        a _        e d     d d     d d     d l     n
        //e       h d       v r    1     2     3     4     5     6     2     s

        //  BAL D.BUNDY TAM C.ARCHER     7.5  7.48  8.08  7.00  5.58  4.70.     .    6.46
        //  CIN H.BAILEY ATL S.NEWCOMB    9.0  9.72 10.08 10.00 11.62 11.51.     .   10.73

        foreach (HtmlNode pre in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//pre"))
        {
            textBox1.Text += pre.InnerText + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

I want to capture the lines that look like the 3rd and 4th lines ignoriing the preceeding lines.

The foreach is executed, but it has  pre.InnerText.Length of 1642 which is the total of the pre-formatted text.  I want to capture a line of data.  e.g. Line 3 & 4.

Comment: So you're saying the inner contents of your `foreach` loop are never executed? (i.e. that `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//pre").GetEnumerator().MoveNext() == false`)

Comment: The inner loop is executed, but it captures all of the pre-formatted text.  I just want to capture the lines of text.  Line 3 and 4 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition `<pre>` tags are preformatted text, so you need to parse the `InnerText` property yourself. The sample you gave above is consistently formatted, so split the `InnerText` into a collection of lines, and then use a `Regex` to capture the lines you want. *Tested and working* code example:

```
var url = @"http://www.thepredictiontracker.com/basepred.php";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
var regexMatch = new Regex(
    @"^\s*[A-Z]{3}\s+[A-Z]\.[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]{3}", 
    RegexOptions.Compiled
);
foreach (HtmlNode pre in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//pre"))
{
    foreach (var line in pre.InnerText.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }))
    {
        if (regexMatch.IsMatch(line))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line.Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks kuujinbo, It works.  Your answer was complete.  I appreciate the help.